# How to upload Wordpress to cPanel but still keeping the configuration?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I've worked my project using WordPress on localhost first (I use XAMPP). And now I've just uploaded all of my WordPress files to cPanel. The database also has been imported too. I have also configured the `wp-config` to connect it to the WordPress database. But when I view the website, it shows WordPress installation page (choosing language, and so on) like if I install it for the first time.

Then, how to upload WordPress files that I have configured before on XAMPP to my cPanel? Thank you very much for the answer. I will really appreciate it!

*NOTE: I use Themeum Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order to do this is:

1. Move your files to the remote server via FTP (check your hosting to see how to do that).
2. Import your DB to the remote server - Open PhpMyAdmin and create a new user with your settings from `wp-config.php` , and check the option to create a db with the same name and grrant all privileges.
3. Run SQL queries that will change the DB from your localhost installation to the current one. here are the statements I use:

   ```
   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl'; 
   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl'); 
   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl'); 
   UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');`
   ```

You can do it from the phpmyadmin SQL tab on your selected DB. just change the URL.

4. Connect to your site to see everything works.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you now the problem has gone. It looks like it was because of my own fault. I was not careful in setting the `wp-config.php`, specifically in putting the database name.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the tables you imported are owned by the same MySQL user that you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Go over phpmyadmin in database your wp table name, set first 2 options in wp-config, set url and home to your website url.